# Spark installation - warning and error when running spark-shell command

Tags: apache-spark, windows-10

I have Hadoop 2.7.7, Java JDK 13, and Spark 2.4.4. Hadoop is set-up and running correctly. I have defined my paths correctly, and double-checked them. When I run `spark-shell` command I get the following list of warnings and errors:

[image]

What's causing this?

Comment: Check your configuration somewhere you have provided incorrectly configuration or delimiter which is causing Array out of Index. It might be possible that it is not getting all configuration information that is required.

Comment: @Nikk Actually, switching to JDK 8 solved the problem. There was nothing wrong with the configuration itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JDK 8 instead of JDK 13 solved the problem without changing anything else, including the path configurations. Spark just does not seem to like any version of Java past version 8.